# PHP array to HTML select

Tags: php, html

I have a list of countries in this format in an external file:

```
<? $countries=array();
$countries['AF']='Afghanistan';
$countries['AL']='Albania';
$countries['DZ']='Algeria';
$countries['AS']='American Samoa';
$countries['AD']='Andorra';
$countries['AO']='Angola'; ?>
```

How can I make them list as options in a HTML select, with the abreviation (ex: 'AF') being the value and the full name of the country, the displayed text?

Ex: `<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foreach($countries as $cc => $name) {
    echo '<option value="' . $cc . '">' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

If the external file only contains the country list (btw, use `<?php` instead of `<?`!!), simply `include` it.

Comment: Not all environments support <? shorttag. You should never use <?.

Comment: The `<?` notation is called a *[short open tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)*, and may not be enabled on all servers.

Comment: `<?` requires short_open_tag to be set to on in php.ini. For this reason, code using it is not considered portable.

Answer (score 3):

```
<select>
<?php
    foreach( $countries as $id=>$name) 
        echo "<option value=\"$id\">$name</option>";
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Escape orgies are ugly; both PHP and HTML work fine with either `'` or `"`

Comment: `echo '<option value="', $id, '">', $name, '</option>';` would be amazing. It would make novice scripters roll their eyes. :D

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
  printf("\t<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n", $key, $value);
}
```